# d3.js replacing random() data function with asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

I'm trying to adapt Mike Bostock's swimlane calendar http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173 and replace the random data generation function with a JSON file.

```
d3.json("random.json", function(data) {
//  console.log(d3.entries(data));
//var data = randomData()
var lanes = data.lanes;
var items = data.items;
var now = new Date();
.....
});
```

where the data file looks like the output of the random() function:

```
{"lanes":[{"id":0,"label":"lane 0"},{"id":1,"label":"lane 1"},{"id":2,"label":"lane 2"},{"id":3,"label":"lane 3"},{"id":4,"label":"lane 4"}],"items":[{"id":0,"lane":0,"start":"2012-01-21T18:00:00.000Z","end":"2012-01-26T21:00:00.000Z","class":"past","desc":"This is a description."},{"id":1,"lane":0,"start":"2012-01-28T18:00:00.000Z","end":"2012-02-02T21:00:00.000Z","class":"past","desc":"This is a description."},{"id":2,"lane":0,"start":"2012-02-05T13:00:00.000Z","end":"2012-02-10T18:00:00.000Z","class":"past","desc":"This is a description."},{"id":3,"lane":0,"start":"2012-02-13T15:00:00.000Z","end":"2012-02-15T13:00:00.000Z","class":"past","desc":"This is a description."},{"id":4,"lane":0,"start":"2012-02-17T16:00:00.000Z","end":"2012-02-22T13:00:00.000Z","class":"past","desc":"This is a description."},{"id":5,"lane":0,"start":"2012-02-23T13:00:00.000Z","end":"2012-02-23T21:00:00.000Z","class":"past","desc":"This is a description."},{"id":6,"lane":0,"start":"2012-02-24T18:00:00.000Z","end":"2012-03-01T14:00:00.000Z","class":"past","desc":"This is a description."}
```

the error I get is:

> TypeError: n.getFullYear is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've parsed the JSON you need to explicitly convert the dates from strings into the Date type.

In the given example the start and end variables are created as Date objects

```
var dtS = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + randomNumber(1,5), randomNumber(8, 16), 0, 0);
var dateOffset =  randomNumber(0,7);
var dt = new Date(dtS.getFullYear(), dtS.getMonth(), dtS.getDate() + dateOffset, randomNumber(dateOffset === 0 ? dtS.getHours() + 2 : 8, 18), 0, 0);
```

You can do this by iterating through your items and converting each item individually

```
items.forEach(function(d){
  d.start = new Date(d.start);
  d.end = new Date(d.end);
});
```

d3 has some helpers for working with more complex date strings. You can read more about them here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#parse

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format.iso.parse;
items.forEach(function(d){
  d.start = parseDate (d.start);
  d.end = parseDate (d.end);
});
```

Comment: this is great- I am going to see if I can substitute date items in the array rather than post-processing them.

Comment: In lieu of iterating through the items, I replaced all references to 'd.start' and 'd.end' with
      d.start = new Date(d.start);
      d.end = new Date(d.end);
works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because in your `data.items` your `start` and `end` properties are strings and not dates (the `randomData()` function returns them as dates).

```
...
var now = new Date();
items.forEach(function(d){
  d.start = new Date(d.start);
  d.end = new Date(d.end);
});
...
```